# Pangram detector not recognizing every pangram

Tags: java, string, pangram

I've written a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) detector in Java.

Some of the test cases are giving the wrong answer, for example:
"We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize".

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        s.toLowerCase();
       if(s.length()<26){
           System.out.println("not pangram");
           System.exit(1);
       }
        char arr[]=s.toCharArray();
        int counter=0;
        char c='a';
        for(c='a';c<='z';c++){
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[i]==c){
                    counter++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(counter==26){
            System.out.println("pangram");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("not pangram");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Would be terribly helpful to know what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: The program recognizes a 'pangram'. A sentence that contains all the letters of alphabet and obviously this algorithm needs a lot of corrections :)

Answer (score 4):

```
s.toLowerCase();
```

should be

```
s = s.toLowerCase();
```

since String is immutable, so `toLowerCase()` returns a new `String` and doesn't change the original `String`.

Your code failed to detect the Pangram for the input `"We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize"` since your loops tested the original input `String` instead of the lower case version of it, and there are no occurences of `w` in the original `String`.

Comment: Why do you do this? There are hundreds of duplicates of this. If this really is the answer, then vote to close as duplicate. The question is incredibly poor to begin with. Instead of answering, ask for clarification or edit it yourself if you understand it better than all of us. Please read the help center, specifically [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)'s section about answering well-asked questions.

Comment: This is not duplicate. The questioner doesn't know where the problem is.